# Error during production build in Ionic Application

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

During production testing on my android device I have the following error:

```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: Must call super constructor in derived class before 
accessing 'this' or returning from derived constructor
        at new <anonymous> (main.js:1)
        at t.create (vendor.js:1)
        at vendor.js:1
        at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
        at Object.onInvoke (vendor.js:1)
        at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
        at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
        at t.run (vendor.js:1)
        at e._bootstrapModuleFactoryWithZone (vendor.js:1)
        at e.bootstrapModuleFactory (vendor.js:1)
```

The problem is I have no clue what is the reason, because there is no way I can tell from this error message.

My components list:

```
Pages:
    LoginPage <--- starting page
    SignupPage,
    CalendarPage,
    SettingsPage,
    WorkTimePage,
    RestorePasswordPage,
    ChangePasswordPage,
    NotificationsPage,
    TrackerPage,
    EmptyTrackerPage,
    CreateProjectContentPage,
    MenuTakenSlotContentPage,
    EmptySlotContentPage,
    TakenSlotContentPage,
    ColorPickerContentPage,
    ProjectSelectContentPage,
    TimeConfirmContentPage,
    MenuOfflineWorkContentPage,
    CalendarEventSelectContentPage,
    AgreementContentPage,
    ProjectsPage,
    IntroductionPage,
    ProjectDetailsContentPage,
    WeekSwapContentPage,
    WorkTimeSwapContentPage,
    SettingsSelectContentPage,
    ModalPage

Providers: 
    Settings, 
    Auth, 
    Data,
    Connectivity
```

How can I fix this? Or how at least check what is the problem?

This is place where error occurs:

```
constructor(t) {} <----- here
        get _BrowserXhr_29() {
            return null == this.__BrowserXhr_29 && (this.__BrowserXhr_29 = new p.c),
            this.__BrowserXhr_29
        }
```

Comment: show the components

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka you want just a list of components?

Comment: no show the code

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka but code of what? There are about 10 000 lines of code

Comment: It means you are extending a class somewhere in your code, and in your construction you are not calling "super()" before using "this".  Assuming you are getting the issue on startup, I would start by looking at the LoginPage and any components used within it.

Comment: @Blueberry this is weird because I don't use any class extensions in my entire application..

Comment: Any external libraries?

Comment: @Blueberry used in my login-page? only lodash